# Any tool to help writing programing article with MS Office Word

Tags: java, plugins, ms-word, ms-office

All! When I use **MS office 2010 Word** to write an article about Java, I always need to embed some Java code into the document. I wonder whether there is such a plugin for Word, or another software tool, that can help me do such a job.

Especially features on code formatting and keywords highlighting are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to get syntax highlighted text in Word. Here are some I know:

**Eclipse + OpenOffice Writer** (Word should do this as well)

1. Mark and copy a code section in Eclipse
2. Paste into Writer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) or Word (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) as HTML or RTF text

**Using Notepad++**

1. Paste the code section to Notepad++
2. Select the appropriate syntax highlighting
3. Use the NppExport Plugin to export to a RTF file
4. Open the file with Word

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ifcx.org/wiki/Wings.html will let you embed live code and execute it in a document, but it requires open office and some plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/), which can export to multiple formats (including HTML, RTF and even SVG!), and has many themes.